# text-align syntax for sifr?

Tags: sifr, text-alignment, text-align

I'm having trouble finding usage/syntax for the text-align feature of sifr. This feature goes inside the flashvars parameter correct? So would it be something like:

sIFR.replace(fontname, {
  selector: 'h1',
  wmode: 'transparent',
  flashvars: 'textalign=center'
});

I tried the above with no luck using r436 build.

Comment: The properties are case-sensitive, it needs to be 'textAlign'.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you only need to edit the all.css file. [Here's](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/how-do-i-change-the-text-alignment/) someone talking about this.

If you don't want to change the css styling of a root element, then you can specify what CSS selection you are applying your sifr is referring to with the `sSelector`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing sIFR 2 and 3 syntax. `flashvars` no longer exists, for sIFR 3 specify it in the replacement CSS:

```
sIFR.replace(fontname, { selector: 'h1', css: '.sIFR-root { textalign: center; }' });
```

You can also specify `background-color` here, so you don't need to use transparency.